# How to align radiobutton with its text?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, android-radiobutton

My `RadioButtons` are slightly above the text attached with them. As shown in the figure, how to resolve this issue?

I want buttons to be positioned as normal. Which means the `RadioButton` circle should be visible in the middle alignment to the text written in front of it.

[image]

Following is the `activity_main.xml` file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@layout/backrepeat"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/azadRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="آزاد"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/qafiaRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="قافیہ"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sabiqaRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="سابقہ"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </RadioGroup>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:onClick="Finder"
        android:text="تلاش"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="359dp"
        android:layout_height="377dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:scrollbarSize="22dip"

        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please post some code of your xml.

Comment: added xml. you may read it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you align right with `gravity="right"` which implicitly aligned button `right/top`, You can **override** that with add flag `center` besides `right`.

```
<RadioButton
   ...
   android:gravity="right|center"
   ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<RadioButton
    ...
    android:textAlignment="center"
    ... />
```

That should align the text of the radio button in the center which should position the text according to your criteria.